# How to publish Event Hub events to Event Grid Topic with Azure SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I would like to set an Event Hub to publish events to an Event Grid Topic using Azure SDK.

This can be done in Azure Portal straight from the Event Hub Namespace, creating an Event Grid System Topic.

However, I can't seem to find a proper way using Azure SDK to either create an Event Grid System Topic, or create an Event Grid custom Topic and setting it as an endpoint for the Event Hub Namespace.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is available, perhaps a bit scattered. If you navigate to the Event Grid [documentation site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/), the Reference node in the menu tree has all the supported languages/SDKs. For .NET, it will bring you to the article on how to publish and subscribe ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/eventgrid?view=azure-dotnet)). To manage topics, you would need the [management SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/eventgrid/management?view=azure-dotnet) and the samples are available [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/event-grid-dotnet-publish-consume-events).

Note that the samples are on the slightly outdated version of the management SDK (related [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/12246)) but you should be able to up the versions and use the samples.

Comment: Thanks Sean.
I have reached these sources, unfortunately didn't find a proper way to create a Topic object as an endpoint to an Event Hub, nor a System Topic object (using Azure.Microsoft.Management.EventGrid.Models package).

Tried to "play" a little bit with creating a Topic object with type & endpoint parameters, unsuccessfully.

Comment: Sorry to hear about the troubles. I did [ping on the issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/12246#issuecomment-657689730) describing _exactly_ this kind of scenario where new users should not struggle to use the SDKs. At this point, Microsoft needs to step up. Sorry it didn't help you.

Comment: Thanks, your help is appreciated nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually used REST API to make HTTP request for creating an Event Grid System Topic.
Documentation for the API request:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/version2020-04-01-preview/systemtopics/createorupdate

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Phew !! This issue screwed my mind for 3 days & I had almost lost hope but finally it worked.
Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/eventgrid?view=azure-java-stable

Code

```
    final String clientId = "clientId";
    final String tenantId = "tenantId";
    final String clientSecret = "clientSecret";
    final String subscriptionId = "subscriptionId";

    ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId, tenantId, clientSecret,
            AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
    credentials.withDefaultSubscriptionId(subscriptionId);

    EventGridManager eventGridManager = EventGridManager.configure().authenticate(credentials,
            credentials.defaultSubscriptionId());
    
    eventGridManager.eventSubscriptions().define("subscription")
    .withScope("/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts/{storageAccountName}")
    .withEventDeliverySchema(EventDeliverySchema.EVENT_GRID_SCHEMA)
    .withDestination(new WebHookEventSubscriptionDestination().withEndpointUrl("{valid https url}"))
    .create();
```

This creates a system topic with a subscription